# Why order_by has miscellaneous behavior with nulls in databases?

Tags: python, django, sql-order-by

There is a difference between the behaviour of `ORDER_BY` in cases where value is `null`, for instance, Postgres treats these values as greatest. I guess there is no "correct" behaviour and it depends on a particular case. I found this after some of the tests on the SQLite started to fail.

For example:

```
# Postgres
>>> Person.objects.order_by('age').values('age')
>>> <QuerySet [{'age': 10}, {'age': 30}, {'age': None}]>

# SQLite
>>> Person.objects.order_by('age').values('age')
>>> <QuerySet [{'age': None}, {'age': 10}, {'age': 30}]>
```

It is possible to bring behaviour on all databases to one style? And by the way, why there are differences in behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because there is ***no consensus*** on how a database should order `NULL` values.

You can make the order non-ambiguous by specifying if the `NULL`s should be put first or last by using an `F` object, and call [**`.asc(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.asc) or [**`.desc(..)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#django.db.models.Expression.desc) on it, and set the `nulls_first=…` *or* `nulls_last=…` to `True`. For example:

```
from django.db.models import F

Person.objects.order_by(F('age').asc(nulls_last=True)).values('age')
```

This will then result in a query that looks like (SQLite):

```
SELECT age
FROM person
ORDER BY age IS NULL, age;
```

Since `False`/`0` is ordered before `True`/`1`, it will thus order `age`s that are not `NULL` before the `age`s who are `NULL`.

The same query in Postgres looks like:

```
SELECT age
FROM person
ORDER BY age ASC NULLS LAST;
```